# par(mfcol=c(2,1)) and blank second row

Tags: r

I am wondering why the following bit of code doesn't produce the two plots one below the other.

```
data(mtcars)
library(randomForest)

mtcars.rf <- randomForest(mpg ~ ., data=mtcars, ntree=1000, keep.forest=FALSE,
                          importance=TRUE)
png("rf1.png", width=6, height=6, units="in", res=100)
par(mfcol=c(2,1))
varImpPlot(mtcars.rf)
plot(mtcars.rf, log="y")
dev.off()
```

This just produces

[image]

with a blank second row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that varImpPlot redefines the plotting area, and then resets it to the previous value. This means it acts as if you called `par(mfcol=c(2,1))` *after* the `varImpPlot` line. If you extract the varImpPlot plotting data you can plot the two dotcharts yourself (you can use `layout` rather than `par` to split the plotting area into different shaped regions):

```
data(mtcars)
library(randomForest)

mtcars.rf <- randomForest(mpg ~ ., data=mtcars, ntree=1000, keep.forest=FALSE,
                          importance=TRUE)
varImpData <- varImpPlot(mtcars.rf) # calculate this outside the plot

png("rf1.png", width=6, height=6, units="in", res=100)
layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,3), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE))
dotchart(varImpData[,c(1)])
dotchart(varImpData[,c(2)])
plot(mtcars.rf, log="y")
dev.off()
```