# R Write to file Plot consists of sub plots

Tags: r, plot, par

I have this code which suppose to write a plot consists of a number of small sub plots to a file.

```
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))
    par(mfrow=c(3,3))

    filepath <- paste(getwd(),'/','BP_',product_name,'.jpg',sep="")
    jpeg(filepath)

    boxplot(normalized.price_shipping~rank, data=data.selected, main=toupper("Normalized Price By Rank Levels"), font.main=3, cex.main=1.2, xlab="Rank Levels", ylab="Price+Shpping", font.lab=3, col="darkgreen")
    #dev.off()

    #filepath <- paste(getwd(),'/','BP_normalized.seller_feedback_score_',product_name,'.jpg',sep="")
    #jpeg(filepath)
    boxplot(normalized.seller_feedback_score~rank, data=data.selected, main=toupper("normalized.seller_feedback_score By Rank Levels"), font.main=3, cex.main=1.2, xlab="Rank Levels", ylab="normalized.seller_feedback_score", font.lab=3, col="darkgreen")
    #dev.off()

    #filepath <- paste(getwd(),'/','BP_normalized.seller_positive_feedback_percent~rank_',product_name,'.jpg',sep="")
    #jpeg(filepath)
    boxplot(normalized.seller_positive_feedback_percent~rank, data=data.selected, main=toupper("normalized.seller_positive_feedback_percent By Rank Levels"), font.main=3, cex.main=1.2, xlab="Rank Levels", ylab="normalized.seller_positive_feedback_percent", font.lab=3, col="darkgreen")
    #dev.off()

    #filepath <- paste(getwd(),'/','BP_keywords_title_assoc~rank_',product_name,'.jpg',sep="")
    #jpeg(filepath)
    boxplot(keywords_title_assoc~rank, data=data.selected, main=toupper("keywords_title_assoc By Rank Levels"), font.main=3, cex.main=1.2, xlab="Rank Levels", ylab="keywords_title_assoc", font.lab=3, col="darkgreen")
    #dev.off()

    #filepath <- paste(getwd(),'/','BP_log10_seller_feedback_score~rank_',product_name,'.jpg',sep="")
    #jpeg(filepath)
    boxplot(log10(seller_feedback_score)~rank, data=data.selected, main=toupper("seller_log10_feedback_score By Rank Levels"), font.main=3, cex.main=1.2, xlab="Rank Levels", ylab="seller_feedback_score", font.lab=3, col="darkgreen")


    dev.off()
```

However, in the file written to the file system, I can only see the last plot from from the 5 Box Plots I needed to see.
Any idea why ?

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13175556/1414455

Comment: could not find my answer there. I think my problem is different - I can successfully see all the sub plots inside RStudio, however when writing the plot to file only the last plot is shown in the file

Answer (score 1):

I think, it because you should first create jpeg file, and then use par function.

```
 filepath <- paste(getwd(),'/','BP_',product_name,'.jpg',sep="")
    jpeg(filepath)

par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))
par(mfrow=c(3,3))
etc.
```